# Fedora 20 boots in emergency mode

Tags: fedora, boot

After reformatting a disk that I think had nothing to do with the Fedora installation, it now boots always in emergency mode, no matter what "Fedora" option I choose in the bootloader

My disk configuration:
I have 3 500GB disk in an array with Intel Matrix Storage. The array was split in 2 disks. One of them, Raid 0. Fedora (home, root, swap) are partitions of this disk (they aren't the only ones). The other disk in the array used to be Raid 5. I changed it to Raid 0 and formatted it to NTFS from Windows. After that, I can't boot Fedora.
Windows is on a separate 1TB disk.

In the journal log, I see "red stuff" including:

- tsc: fast tsc calibration failed
- Failed to find module 'vboxdrv'/'vboxnetflt'/'vboxnetadp'
- Failed to start Load Kernel Modules
- inotify_add_watch(7, /dev/sda2, 10) failed: No such file or directory
- inotify_add_watch(7, /dev/sda4, 10) failed: No such file or directory
- inotify_add_watch(7, /dev/sda3, 10) failed: No such file or directory
- inotify_add_watch(7, /dev/sda1, 10) failed: No such file or directory
- [sdi] No Caching mode page found. Assuming drive cache: write through
- Dependency failed for Mark the need to relabel after reboot

Clearly I have no idea which of these errors where already there when the PC worked normally. The /etc/modules.load.d folder is empty (not sure if it should be)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Wait, RAID 0 is normally a way to combine *multiple* disks together where performance is all that counts; data is not redundant in any way.

Comment: @derobert right

Comment: Up to know, all I did was fiddle around with fsck. Also yumremoved Virtual Box but the vboxdrv/etc errors didn't stop (why is VB so important that I haven't even logged in and it already tried to load its modules? I never even used it yet)

Comment: Fedora 20 is *long* out of maintenance. If you need long life, migrate to e.g. CentOS.

Answer (score 4):

All solved.
In the /etc/fstab file, it was trying to mount a partition that isn't there any more. It seems it considered this bad enough to enter emergency mode!

Comment: Any tips for someone who only has `/dev/mapper/fedora-root /` and `/dev/mapper/fedora-swap swap`? I can't seem to figure out how to make it boot solidly.

Comment: Just had the same issue with fedora 24 after removing a secondary disk that was mapped from `/etc/fstab`. Thanks for the fix.